# Business data security under Android - recognize backup/restore attacks

Tags: android, security, data-manipulation

For a mobile Android application (I have to do the same for iOS, but this question focuses on Android only) I have to prevent data manipulation. Concrete I want to prevent that the user backups and restores the application directory and starts my application without an active data connection (I have to allow offline mode to a certain grade) so that I cannot detect inside my mobile application that the data is in an "old" state.

With this attack the user is able to go "back in time" to an application state which brings him advantages. As a root user it is very easy to perform such a "backup/restore" attack with apps like "Titanium Backup". However I do not want to block users with root (I have also root on my phone) nor do I want to block backups.

Instead I want to recognize a backup/restore attach: my approach is to to link my application data (lets focus on the database) with an "anchor point":

- for every relevant modification in the database I create an unique id which I store in the database inside the same transaction
- the same unique id is stored as an "anchor point" somewhere in the system
- whenever the application starts, it compares the anchor point with the id inside the database
- if they are different I will not allow offline mode - the user has to go online to generate a valid database state - so the majority of the users can stay offline.

This approach will protect me against the "backup/restore" attack only when the "anchor point" is not included in the backup which means it is hidden somewhere in the system (security through obscurity = bad security) or better stored in a systems registry which can only be modified by my application (security by design).

So the questions are:

- What is a good place / technique for storing an anchor point?
- What other approach could you recommend instead of using an "anchor point"?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I found only this similar question here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400477/how-to-protect-detect-database-restore-on-android-device?rq=1 - however I don't think that the external directory will provide much security.